# ¿Cambiar el color del placeholder de un input de texto mediante JavaScript o, mejor aún, CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, entrada

Quiero cambiar el color del marcador de posición de este input. ¿Es posible?

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your input here">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con css:

```
::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
    color: red;
    opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
    color: red;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Ah! era tan simple. Mil gracias!